# Die »nullte Stelle« der Sätze

Tags: word-order

Erwägen Sie die zwei Sätze:

1. Ich mag Hunde, darum **habe ich** auch einen.
2. Ich mag Hunde, aber **ich habe** keinen.

Ich weiß, dass im Satz das Verb an der zweiten Stelle stehen muss. Aber, im zweiten Satz scheint das Verb an der dritten Stelle zu stehen. Darum sagt man, dass *aber* an der »nullten Stelle« des Satzes steht.

Meine Frage ist: Warum kann *aber* an der »nullten Stelle« stehen, aber nicht *darum*?

---

Consider the two sentences:

1. Ich mag Hunde, darum **habe ich** auch einen.
2. Ich mag Hunde, aber **ich habe** keinen.

I know that the verb must occupy the 2<sup>nd</sup> place in a sentence. However, in the 2<sup>nd</sup> sentence, the verb seems to occupy the 3<sup>rd</sup> place. Therefore, we say that *aber* occupies the "0<sup>th</sup> place".

My question is: Why can *aber* occupy the "0<sup>th</sup> place", but not *darum*?

Comment: Is there a certain rule that the verb has to be in third place? To me 'darum' seems to be in 0th place, as well - even if the verb isn't in third place.

Comment: The verb has to be in the second place. Darum | **habe** | ich | auch | einen.

Comment: Yes, I know. However, I don't see why the word 'darum' bothers you, because it is in the 0th place, isn't it?

Comment: I think 'darum' is in the 1st place.

Comment: So 'Hunde' would be the 0th place?

Comment: That is a different sentence.

Comment: I am really confused right know. Are you saying there is no 0th place in this sentence (the one containing 'darum')?

Comment: Yes, of course we count from 1,2,3,...

Comment: So why is 'aber' the 0th place?

Comment: To fit our rule that the verb has to be in the 2nd place.

Comment: The verb is not always at position 2. In relative clauses it is at the last position. You made this error also in the sentences of your question. I corrected it. See http://german.stackexchange.com/posts/35045/revisions to compare your version with the correct version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

»*Darum*« ist ein Adverb, »*aber*« ist aber eine nebenordnende Konjunktion. Nebenordnende Konjunktionen gehören weder zum ersten, noch zum zweiten Satz, sondern stehen als Verbindungselement zwischen zwei gleichwertigen Sätzen. Die Formulierung »*die Konjunktion steht an Stelle 0 des zweiten Satzes*« ist daher eigentlich irreführend, weil sie die Konjunktion als Teil des zweiten Satzes betrachtet. Darüber, welche Sicht die richtige ist, gibt es unter Experten aber unterschiedliche Meinungen.

Adverbien hingegen verbinden keine Sätze. (Semantisch, also auf der Ebene der Bedeutungen, ist das durchaus der Fall, aber nicht auf der rein grammatischen Ebene, um die es hier geht):

> **Darum** beginnen auch manche Vollsätze mit einem Adverb.

Der vorige Satz ist ein Beispiel für einen Hauptsatz, der mit einem Adverb beginnt, welches die Position 1 des Satzes besetzt. Das Verb (*beginnen*) steht, wie in jedem vollständigen Hauptsatz, an Position 2. Lässt man das Adverb weg, muss etwas anderen (meist das Substantiv, hier »*manche Vollsätze*«) an die Stelle 1 rücken:

> **Manche Vollsätze** beginnen mit einem Adverb.

Das Adverb kann aber auch hinter dem Verb stehen, denn es ist ja ein Begleiter des Verbs:

> Manche Vollsätze beginnen **darum** mit einem Adverb.

---

Dein erstes Beispiel ist tatsächlich nichts anderes als eine Aneinanderreihung zweier Hauptsätze, die man auch getrennt als zwei Vollsätze schrieben kann:

> Ich mag Hunde.
>   Darum habe ich auch einen.

In beiden Sätzen steht das Verb an Position 2. Im ersten Satz steht das Substantiv an Position 1, im zweiten steht dort ein Adverb, so dass das Substantiv an die dritte Position rücken muss, denn in jedem Hauptsatz **muss** ein Bestandteil des Prädikats (das hier in beiden Fällen aus jeweils nur einem Verb besteht) die Position 2 belegen.

---

Dein zweiter Satz kann auch in zwei getrennte Sätze geteilt werden, dann muss aber die Konjunktion weggelassen werden, denn sie gehört weder zum ersten, noch zum zweiten Satz:

> Ich mag Hunde.
>   Ich habe keinen.

Das Wort »aber« ist eine nebenordnende Konjunktion. Das heißt, es verbindet zwei Sätze (*Konjunktion*), die gleichrangig sind (*nebengeordnet*).

Beide Sätze sind Hauptsätze, bei denen an Position 1 das Subjekt und an Position 2 das Prädikat steht.

---

Die Beantwortung deiner Frage ist hier eigentlich zu Ende. Ich gehe aber trotzdem auch noch auf etwas anderes ein, weil du das im deutschen Teil deiner Frage [konsequent falsch](https://german.stackexchange.com/revisions/35045/1) gemacht hast, und inhaltlich auch deiner eigentlichen Frage nahe steht:

Es gibt auch unterordnende Konjunktionen, die einen Nebensatz einleiten. Das Wort »*dass*« ist eine solche unterordnende Konjunktionen:

> Ich weiß, **dass** im Satz das Verb an der zweiten Stelle steht.

<sup>*(Dieser Satz stammt aus deinem Posting, ich habe nur das Prädikat vereinfacht. Statt »stehen muss« verwende ich »steht«, damit das Prädikat aus nur einem Verb besteht.)*</sup>
Hier ist »*Ich weiß*« ein Hauptsatz, der als weitere Ergänzung kein gewöhnliches Objekt hat, sondern einen ganzen Satz. Dieser Ergänzungs-Satz ist dem Hauptsatz untergeordnet, weil er eine grammatische Funktion im Hauptsatz hat. Er ist so etwas ähnliches wie ein Objekt des Hauptsatzes.

Der Teil

> dass im Satz das Verb an der zweiten Stelle steht

ist dieser Nebensatz. Weil das aber kein Hauptsatz ist, sondern ein untergeordneter Nebensatz, gilt hier für die Position des Verbs eine andere Regel:

- In einem Nebensatz muss das Verb (im Beispiel: »*steht*«) an der letzten Position stehen.

Auch wichtig für Nebensätze: Die Konjunktion selbst (hier das Wort »*dass*«) steht **im** Nebensatz. Sie ist also ein Teil des Nebensatzes. Das unterscheidet nebenordnende Konjunktionen (»*und, aber, ...*«), die zwischen den Sätzen stehen, von den unterordnenden Konjunktionen (»*dass, während, ...*«), die ein Teil des untergeordneten Satzes sind.

Comment: Darum ist meine Frage: Warum ist *darum* nicht eine Konjunktion? Es verbindet auch 2 Sätze, die getrennt werden sein. "Ich mag Hunde. Ich habe auch einen." Man kann auch schrieben: "Aber ich habe keinen."...

Comment: Ich habe es in meiner Antwort bereits erwähnt: »*Darum*« schafft nur auf der Ebene der Bedeutungen eine Verbindung. Das ist, wenn du willst, eine *logische* Verbindung, aber es ist **keine** grammatische Verbindung! »*Darum*« gehört einer Wortart an, die nicht in der Lage ist, grammatische Verbindungen zwischen zwei Sätzen herzustellen. »*Darum*« ist ein Adverb. Es ist also Wort, dass eine nähere Angabe zu einer Aussage macht. Das Wort »darum« bewirkt, dass die Aussage, zu der es gehört, als Begründung für etwas anderes zu interpretieren ist. Das ist aber eine semantische Verbindung.

Comment: Das Wort »aber« gehört zu einer anderen Wortart als »darum«. »Aber« ist eine Konjunktion, kein Adverb. Konjunktionen stellen zwar auch auf semantischer Ebene eine Verbindung her (im Fall von »*aber*« einen Gegensatz), aber zusätzlich stellen Konjunktionen auch auf grammatischer Ebene eine Verbindung zwischen zwei Sätzen her. Diese grammatische Funktion existiert bei Adverbien, wie z.B. *darum* nicht.

Comment: Wenn, wie du hast gesagt, *darum* ist keine Konjunktion, »Ich mag Hunde.« und »Darum habe ich auch einen.« sollen Vollsätze sein, oder? Denn warum kann man die Vollsätze verbinden? Kann man in Deutsch alle Sätze verbinden?

Comment: Du ignorierst den Unterschied zwischen Grammatik und Semantik. Der Satz »*Der Tisch trinkt ein Auto.*« (*the table drinks a car*) ist grammatisch völlig korrekt, aber semantisch völliger Unsinn. In der Grammatik geht es nur um technische Funktionen, nicht um den Sinn. »*Darum*« ist ein Adverb, und ein Adverb kann auf der **grammatischen** Ebene nichts miteinander verbinden. Die Semantik ist etwas anders. In der Semantik geht es um Bedeutungen, um den Sinn, der in einer Aussage steckt. Auf der semantischen Ebene stellt das Wort »*darum*« sehr wohl eine Verbindung her.

Comment: Dieses Wort verbindet den Sinn des einen Satzes mit dem Sinn des andern Satzes, und stellt klar, dass das, was ein Satz aussagt, die Ursache dessen ist, was ein anderer Satz aussagt. Das ist natürlich eine Verbindung, aber sie findet ausschließlich auf der sinntragenden Ebene, also in der Semantik statt. Grammatisch kann das Wort »*darum*« trotzdem keine Sätze verbinden. Genau das kann aber das Konjunktions-Wort »*aber*«.

Comment: Ich meine, das wenn *darum* ist keine Konjunktion, warum kann man »Ich mag Hunde, darum habe ich auch einen« schrieben? In Englische, wenn man schreibt 2 Vollsätze zusammen, es heißt eine "run-on sentence" und ist grammatisch nicht.

Comment: »*Kann man in Deutsch alle Sätze verbinden*« - Das kann man in Deutsch genau gleich handhaben wie in Englisch. Auf semantischer Ebene besteht hier kein Unterscheid, denn da geht es nur um Bedeutungen, und diese sind grundsätzlich von der Sprache unabhängig (anderenfalls könnte man nichts von einer Sprache in eine andere übersetzen). Auf grammtischer Ebene sehe ich ebenfalls keinen Unterscheid zwischen Englisch und Deutsch, bin aber kein Experte für Englisch.

Comment: "I like dogs, that is why I have one." Das ist genau die Übersetzung von »Ich mag Hunde, darum habe ich auch einen.«, und es ist **ein** Satz. Du kannst aber auch im Englischen zwei Sätze daraus machen: "I like dogs. That is why I have one." Ganz genau wie im Deutschen.

Comment: "I like dogs, that is why I have one." ist grammatisch falsch in Englisch...

Answer (score 0):

Now I got it ;)

The word 'darum' can't be in 0th place, because it wouldn't sound like proper German if it was. “darum ich habe auch einen“ would not sound good.
Therefore, you could say the word 'darum' requires a verb to be directly following it (not in 0th place). The same applys to 'deshalb' oder auch 'deswegen'.

'Aber', however, can't be followed by a verb. You first need someone/something that does something, as it is in your example (aber **ich** habe...).
That's different in case you would ask a question using 'aber', for example: “Aber hast du denn einen Hund?“

Comment: My question is why the function of "aber" and "darum" are different, not a clarification of the difference.

Comment: Darum has the function to give a reason, aber has the function to point out a condition or a meaning like in your example. I just don't know what else you could want to know, sorry.

Comment: Why does "darum" requires a verb right after it but not "aber"?

Comment: I thought I answered that. Maybe I find something more specific and accurate.

Comment: Your only explanation was "it wouldn't sound like proper German".

Comment: Which is a fact. I am a native German speaker, but apparently I can't explain you any grammatical terms, sorry again.

Comment: @HarmlessPsycho: DHMO hat vollkommen recht: »it wouldn't sound like proper German« ist zwar zutreffend, aber keine Erklärung. Außerdem hilft dieser Hinweis jemanden, der die Sprache gerade erst als Fremdsprache lernt, und der noch kein Sprachgefühl entwickelt hat, herzlich wenig.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Anmerkung angenommen und eingesehen. Gibt definitiv ein up vote auf Ihre Antwort!